# INSERT no se procesa y no arroja error

Tags: php

este es mi codigo que busca guardar un cliente nuevo en mi base de datos de clientes, sin embargo al ejecutarlo no me genera ningun error pero tampoco almacena la información:
soy nueva en programación, y he revisado mil veces que no se me haya quedado nada fuera, pero no se si es un tema de sintaxtis

insertar_cliente.php

```
<?php 
    include_once 'database.php';

    if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){
        $id_cliente=$_POST['id_cliente'];
        $nombres=$_POST['nombres'];
        $apellidos=$_POST['apellidos'];
        $celular=$_POST['celular'];

        if(!empty($id_cliente) && !empty($nombres) && !empty($apellidos) && !empty($celular)){

            }else{
                $consulta_insert=$con->prepare('INSERT INTO clientes(id_cliente,nombres,apellidos,celular) VALUES(:id_cliente,:nombres,:apellidos,:celular)');
                $consulta_insert->execute(array(
                    ':id_cliente' =>$id_cliente,
                    ':nombres' =>$nombres,
                    ':apellidos' =>$apellidos,
                    ':celular' =>$celular,
                    ));
                header('Location: index.php');
            }
        }else{
            echo "<script> alert('Los campos estan vacios');</script>";
        }



?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que la estructura de tu declaración es errónea, es decir:

- Si el botón `guardar` esta definido entonces asignas a las variables el valor que a cada una le toca y que llegan por `$_POST`
- Si ninguna de las variables están vacías entonces haces el `INSERT` y redireccionas
- En caso de que la condición anterior no se cumpla entonces en el primer `ELSE` avisas que los campos están vacíos
- En caso de que el botón `guardar` no esté definido lo notificas en el segundo `ELSE`

Código:

```
include_once 'database.php';

if(isset($_POST['guardar']))
{
    $id_cliente=$_POST['id_cliente'];
    $nombres=$_POST['nombres'];
    $apellidos=$_POST['apellidos'];
    $celular=$_POST['celular'];

    if(!empty($id_cliente) && !empty($nombres) && !empty($apellidos) && !empty($celular))
    {
        $consulta_insert=$con->prepare('INSERT INTO clientes(id_cliente,nombres,apellidos,celular) 
                                        VALUES(:id_cliente,:nombres,:apellidos,:celular)');
        $consulta_insert->execute(array(
            ':id_cliente' =>$id_cliente,
            ':nombres' =>$nombres,
            ':apellidos' =>$apellidos,
            ':celular' =>$celular,
        ));
        header('Location: index.php');
    }else{
         echo "<script> alert('Los campos estan vacios');</script>";
    }
}else{
    echo "El botón guardar no esta definido";  
}
```

Comment: al decir Si el botón guardar esta definido entonces asignas a las variables el valor que a cada una le toca y que llegan por $_POST, revise el html del boton guardar y el value esta Guardar y no guardar, lo arregle y ya funciona perfecto, Muchas Gracias!!!

Comment: Si tienes la solución @SandraNaranjoPáez considera publicarla, de todos modos te aconsejo considerar las observaciones hechas aqui

Comment: la solucion fue, ademas de corregir el orden de mi codigo segun tu sugerencia, el html del boton guardar, tenia el value de Guardar, al cambiar a g minuscula, como en mi codigo de php, y guardo la informacion correctamente,